# Sql Server Convert between UTC-0 string dates and the server local TimeZone

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime, timezone

When I execute the following, when the server's TimeZone is `+01:00`:

```
Convert(datetime, '2015-02-10T23:00:00Z', 127)
```

The result is:

```
10.02.2015 23:00:00
```

That is the Date at `UTC-0`. My expected value would be `11.02.2015 00:00:00`, that is the date converted to the server's TimeZone.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert` function doesn't convert time to `UTC`. It just simply changes the format of the input string. Here is what you need to do.

1. **Find difference in hours between server local time and `UTC` time:**

   ```
   DECLARE @hour INT
   SELECT @hour = DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
   ```
2. **Add the difference to the date you're trying to convert:**

   ```
   SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(hour, @hour, '2015-02-10T23:00:00Z'), 127)
   ```

If you know your timezone difference in hours and you know that it's unlikely to be changed, then use a shorter version:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(hour, -1, '2015-02-10T23:00:00Z'), 127)
```

Comment: Not all time zones offsets are in whole hour increments, and also this won't account for daylight saving time, because the *current* offset is not necessarily the same as the one for the time stamp being converted.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really depend on the time zone setting of a server.  However, if you have a *specific* time zone in mind, you could use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.

After installation:

```
SELECT Tzdb.UtcToLocal('2015-02-10T23:00:00Z', 'Europe/Paris')
```

Choose a time zone [from the list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).